# How to delete entries from an association table requiring look ups from two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-insert, sql-delete

**Background:**

- List item asset_table has columns {asset_tag, asset_id}
- List item contracts table has columns {contract_number, contract_id}
- List item asset_contract table has columns {contract_id, asset_id}

**Problem:**
I have an asset_tag and an list of contract numbers to add and a list of contract numbers to delete.

Right now I do the following:

1. lookup asset_id from asset tag.
2. lookup contract ids from contract numbers.
3. Execute the query to either add or delete the records from the association table.

Is there a way to delete the associations in a single query instead of 3 separate transactions?

Comment: What type of database are you using (e.g. PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: ms sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Deleting from 3 tables means executing delete 3 times.  It is as simple as that.

Comment: Only the asset_contract table is having rows deleted from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete, one portable option uses `exists`

```
delete from asset_contract 
where exists (select 1 from asset a    where a.asset_id    = asset_contract.asset_id    and a.asset_tag       = ?)
  and exists (select 1 from contract c where c.contract_id = asset_contract.contract_id and c.contract_number = ?)
```

To `insert`, you would do:

```
insert into asset_contract (contract_id, asset_id)
select c.contract_id, a.asset_id
from asset a
cross join contract c
where a.asset_tag = ? and c.contract_number = ?
```

The question marks represent the parameters to your query (the asset tag and contract number).

Comment: A piece of information I didn't include in the original problem. A single asset can have associations with multiple contracts. Does the 'select 1' still hold up for the delete in that case?

Comment: @ricknoriega: as I understand your question, yes. Give the query a try. You can replace `delete from` with `select * from` to see the rows that would be deleted by the statement.